# Region unsupported error, Apple Pay, Country: India, Flutter

Tags: flutter, applepay

I tried two packages till now to integrate Apple Pay in my app.

1. [Pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay)
2. [flutter_pay](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pay)

using 1, I was able to see the button on an emulator but not on a real device.

So I tried package 2 [flutter_pay]

But while doing so, When trying to pay, an error/popup occurs on the device saying

```
Cannot Add Cards
The region setting for this device cannot be used with Apple Pay.
```

Have tried searching regarding the same but haven't found a solid solution/source.

Country where the app user base will be active: **India**

`I have gone through the docs and found that apple pay is not supported in India.`

So I have a question if apple pay is not available in India, how come that error doesn't show up when I tried apple pay on other apps.

**How can I integrate the same, what am I missing doing wrong?**

---

**UPDATE**

---

I tried other packages too and looked for many other resources
but didn't found any solution regarding the same,

I tried switching my country region to US in iPhone then I didn't receive a popup with region error,

but still not able to get how are other apps using apple pay on apps, since I can pay in their apps and not able to implement the same on the app I'm building

---

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
**UPDATE**
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

---

Turns out I was on the wrong direction all along.

In apple, `Apple Pay is only to be used if you are dealing with physical goods`.

If you want to do `transactions for digital goods like premium subscriptions, in-app rewards` 
Go for **APPLE IN-APP PURCHASE**

**Apple Pay** & **Apple In-App Purchase** are two different things.

Hope this can help out others, if they get lost like me in future,

Comment: Have you tried it using a vpn?

Comment: @Benyamin no, I haven't but my users are going to be in India, so using VPN just to make it work isn't a feasible solution I guess.

Comment: You need to check all payment solutions abilities on each country. Is there any local equivalent payment service with SDK?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I have tried implementing local payment solutions, but the apple team has rejected my app, saying I need to integrate apple pay, and thus here I am.

Comment: I did not say use VPN to make app work, BUT, I was saying this to find out if the reason is the location because you said india was allowed so I wanted to check this.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe I'll suggest to write back to Apple, force your App to only be available in India and point their limitations in the country. They should let you do that.